# Как вызывать TextBox из другого класса

Tags: c#, парсер

Если создавать в классе Form метод, то вызов TextBox не создает проблем.

```
public void ProductlistItem()
    {
        foreach (var ProducListItem in parserHTML.ProductlistItems())
        {
            //Название фильма
            var namefilm = ProducListItem.Descendants("h2")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                .Equals("th-title nowrap")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();

            LogTex2.Text += namefilm + '\r' + '\n';
        }
```

А вот если создавать отдельный класс в проекте, то встает вопрос, как же все же вызывать TextBox. Или лучше, как по другому создать список (в данном случае названий фильмов) к которому я могу обращаться из другого класса.

Comment: Логика получения данных должна быть отделена от представления. Создавайте отдельный класс, помещайте метод `ProductlistItem` в него. В этом методе заводите список и `namefilm` добавляйте именно в список, а не в TextBox и возвращайте список из метода. Теперь в нужном месте вы можете просто создать экземпляр этого нового класса и, вызвав у него метод ProductlistItem, получить список данных

Comment: Это логически все понятно. Были идеи создавать списки, либо создавать xml файл, но в силу того, что я не так давно занимаюсь C# решил спросить и все таки увидеть пример кода, как все должно выглядеть в идеале. Да и не совсем понятно как записывать в цикле данные в List.

Comment: `var list = new List<string>(); цикл { list.Add(строка); } return list;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно проблема решилась путем инициализации списка (List) с помощью конструктора.

Создаем класс с интересующими нас параметрами для списка.

```
    namespace ivi
{
    public class variables
    {
        public class ParInfo
        {
            public string NameFilm { get; set; }
            public string ImageURl { get; set; }
            public string Quality { get; set; } 
            public string Year { get; set; }
            public string Info { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

После в созданном отдельном классе. Создаем список, добавляя интересующие нас параметры инициализации.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ivi
{
    public class NameFilm
    {
        ParserHTML parserHTML = new ParserHTML();

        //Создание списка (List)
        public List<variables.ParInfo> ProductlistItem()
        {
            var Films = new List<variables.ParInfo>();

            foreach (var ProducListItem in parserHTML.ProductlistItems())
            {

                //Название фильма
                var namefilm = ProducListItem.Descendants("h2")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("th-title nowrap")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();
                //Год
                var year = ProducListItem.Descendants("div")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("short-info")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();
                //Год
                var quality = ProducListItem.Descendants("div")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("th-meta th-qual")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();
                //Описание
                var info = ProducListItem.Descendants("div")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("th-meta th-qual")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();

                //Картинка
                var picturefilm =
                    Regex.Match(
                ProducListItem.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault().GetAttributeValue("src", "//")
                , @"//.*jpg");
                var http = "http:";
                var img = http + picturefilm;

                Films.Add(new variables.ParInfo() { NameFilm = namefilm, Year = year, ImageURl = img, Quality=quality, Info = info});
            }
            return Films;

        }

    }
}
```

И уже из формы обращаемся к инициализированному списку.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ivi
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        ParserHTML parserHTML = new ParserHTML();
        NameFilm namefilm = new NameFilm();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ParserHTML parserHTML = new ParserHTML();
            LogText.Text = parserHTML.LoadPage();
            MainCol();

        }

            public void MainCol()
            {
            #region Boxes
            PictureBox[] boxes = {
  pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5, pictureBox6, pictureBox7, pictureBox8,
                pictureBox9, pictureBox10, pictureBox11, pictureBox12, pictureBox13, pictureBox14, pictureBox15, pictureBox16, pictureBox17, pictureBox18};
            Label[] labels = {
                label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10, label11, label12, label13, label14, label15,
            label16, label17, label18};
            Label[] qal = {
                qual1, qual2, qual3, qual4, qual5, qual6, qual7, qual8, qual9, qual10, qual11, qual12, qual13, qual14, qual15, qual16, qual17, qual18};
            #endregion

            var parsing = namefilm.ProductlistItem();

            int i = 0;

            foreach (var pars in parsing)
                {
                labels[i].Text = parsing[i].NameFilm;
                boxes[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                boxes[i].LoadAsync(parsing[i].ImageURl);
                qal[i].Text = parsing[0].Quality;
                LogTex2.Text += parsing[i].NameFilm + "\r\n";
                LogTex2.Text += parsing[i].ImageURl + "\r\n";
                LogTex2.Text += parsing[i].Quality + "\r\n";
                i++;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Возможно можно сделать проще. Если есть предложения ")

Answer (score 0):

Другой класс

```
public class MyDataProviderClass
{
    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        return new List<string>() {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    }
}
```

Как его вызвать на форме

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    MyDataProviderClass _dataProvider;


    public MyForm()
    {
        _dataProvider = new MyDataProviderClass();
    }

    // ....

    public void ProductlistItem()
    {
        foreach (var film in _dataProvider.GetData())
        {
            LogTex2.Text += film + '\r' + '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1-й способ** через передачу ссылки на форму в конструктор этого другого класса.

Создаем интерфейс

```
interface IMainForm
{
    string Output { get; set; }
}
```

Объявляем, что форма будет его реализовывать

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainForm
```

В форме создаем свойство у которого в качестве бэкинг филд служит нужный текстбокс

```
public string Output
{
    get => _textBoxOutput.Text;
    set => _textBoxOutput.Text = value;
}
```

Такой "другой" класс

```
class ProductData
{
    private readonly IMainForm _form;

    //ctor
    public ProductData(IMainForm form)
    {
        _form = form ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(form));
    }

    public void LoadProductItems()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _form.Output += $"Продукт-{i}" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Форма целиком

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainForm
{
    private ProductData _productData;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _buttonGetOutput.Click += ButtonGetOutput_Click;

        _productData = new ProductData(this);
    }

    public string Output
    {
        get => _textBoxOutput.Text;
        set => _textBoxOutput.Text = value;
    }

    private void ButtonGetOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _productData.LoadProductItems();
    }
}
```

**2-й способ** через привязки.

В наш "другой" класс добавляем `using System.ComponentModel;` и реализуем интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` следующим образом

```
class ProductData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //ctor
    public ProductData()
    {
    }

    private string _OutputText;
    public string OutputText
    {
        get => _OutputText;
        set
        {
            _OutputText = value;
            //!!! Здесь вызываем событие, чтоб текстбокс обновился и показал новые данные
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OutputText)));
        }
    }

    public void LoadProductItems()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            //работаем с собственным свойством
            OutputText += $"Продукт-{i}" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь форма

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private ProductData _productData;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _buttonGetOutput.Click += ButtonGetOutput_Click;

        _productData = new ProductData();

        SetBindings();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //создаем экз. привязки
        Binding binding = new Binding("Text", _productData, nameof(ProductData.OutputText));
        //добавялем привязку к текстбоксу
        _textBoxOutput.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }

    private void ButtonGetOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _productData.LoadProductItems();
    }
}
```

На мой взгляд второй вариант предпочтительнее первого.